# How to check user status on my app? In App Billing

Tags: android, android-studio

I´m implementing In app Billing on my app, which let the user go to a "premium version of the app". In the premium version of the app the user will be able to click 3 buttons and use their functions. But that is not the problem.
The problem is how to check if the user has purchased the "premium version" yet and use all the app functions?
This is my code:

```
private void promptForUpgrade() {
    AlertDialog.Builder upgradeAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    upgradeAlert.setTitle("Upgrade?");
    upgradeAlert.setMessage("Do you want to upgrade to unlimited version?");
    upgradeAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //set progress dialog and start the in app purchase process
            upgradeDialog = ProgressDialog.show(selector.this, "Please wait", "Upgrade transaction in process", true);

              /* TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See the comments on
     *        verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is a SAMPLE, we just use
     *        an empty string, but on a production app you should carefully generate this. */
            String payload = "developerinnovaciones@gmail.com";


            try {
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(selector.this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST,
                        mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Nop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    upgradeAlert.show();
}
```

and this is the OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
    {
        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            alert("Error purchasing: " + result);
            upgradeDialog.dismiss();
        }


        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
            alert("Thank you for upgrade");
            mIsPremium = true;
            setUserStatus(true);
            upgradeDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
};
```

So basically I want to create a method which verify if the user is premium or not.

Hope you can help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `onCreate` method you should check the purchase status in your `mHelper` setup with an `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync` call.

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
       // Oh noes, there was a problem.
       complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
       isBillingSupported = false;
       return;
    }

  // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
  Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");

  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);

  isBillingSupported = true;
  }
});
```

`mGotInventory` I defined like this

```
// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        isPremium = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (isPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));

        updateUi();
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

`isPremium` is a boolean flag defaulting to false.
The `updateUi` method enables/disables buttons depending on the `isPremium` state.

You will probably want to set `isPremium` and call `updateUi` on purchase completion as well to ensure the premium features are enabled immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have a littl question yet. I want to unlock the three "premium buttons" when the pucharse has made, how can i do it?
In my buttons mehod i have something like this
if (!mIsPremium)
{
show a message dialog
}
else
{
the user can go to the premium button activity
}

Sorry for the questions but is the first time im implementing In App Billing on my apps: THansk

Comment: Logic liked that should work.  The onCreate will query the purchases and set the isPremium flag, you can then use it wherever you need to enable premium features.  My updateUi method enables/disables buttons, sounds like you wouldn't need that, just check the flag directly on your button presses.  You are already setting the flag on purchase successful in your existing code so next time the user pressed the button it should work.

Comment: Also worth mentioning you must upload a version with in app purchase to the play store at least in alpha and setup your SKU within the play store dev console to get billing enabled.

Comment: Glad to help.  If my answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted to help both our reputations.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!! Also, if I'm making these purchases these with a test account, how do I reset/refund these purchases so I can test again?